# Как ограничить обзор персонажа Unity 2d C#

Tags: c#, unity3d

Всем привет!
У меня есть персонаж. Что я хочу сделать: персонаж находится в тёмном месте, а значит его обзор ограничен, я хочу сделать область с радиусом R вокруг моего персонажа видимо, а остальное тёмным, естественно, когда персонаж передвигается, то незрмое становится видимым.
Желательно ещё сделать плавный переход от видимой части к тёмной.

Comment: Загугли "туман войны" и поищи решения

Comment: там у камеры настройки покрути, какой-то параметр за дальность отвечает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всем спасибо!
Ответ был найден: необходимо добавить на все спрайты материал затемнения, а на героя повесть point light.

Comment: Если автор скроет видео, ваш ответ потеряет смысл. Дополните пожалуйста ответ подробностями решения так, чтобы можно было понять, о чем речь не переходя по ссылке. Он может оказаться полезным другим посетителям.